# Ouput JSON Array in Apache-Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to output json like the following,

```
{"item":330,"genre":["food", "plant"]}
```

Using

```
a = LOAD 'genres.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (item:int, genre:chararray);
b = GROUP a BY item;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE group, a.genre;
STORE c INTO 'apps_genres.csv' USING JsonStorage();
```

creates psuedo-json

```
{"item":330,"genre":"(food,plant)"}
```

using a string in the place of an array. BagToTuple() causes an error. What is the solution?

**EDIT**

I got it reversed, BagToTuples() creates the pseudo-json, its absence causes the error. The error is still reflected above.